# How to inherit the designing part in c# windows forms application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am making a Windows Forms Application where I have made a template Form where I have added a left menu panel.
Now I am inheriting it in new forms. After creating all the new forms. If I add some new controls in the parent form, the changes reflect in all the new child forms. But if I change the designing, for example, the color of a button in the parent form. These changes don't reflect in the subforms. What to do now?

Comment: why can't you use user controls / custom controls to group the UI aspects together and use them ?

Comment: @ManojChoudhari can you please explain how to do that? any link, please? I am a beginner.